# C# Extract frames, video maker ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, converters

I'm making a program to extract frames from a video file and convert it to less fps and put that frames together to make a video.

I'm using the ffmpeg for the extract frames and when I use the ffmpeg to make a video with those frames its not successful because the size of the video file is more then the original video file.

For example I have a 60 fps 1080 video file and when I use the ffmpeg to extract 25 fps per second of this video then I use the code to put them together its not successful the size of original video is 40 mg and the video I make with those frames is 70 mg so whats wrong?

Video link: https://youtu.be/gabPNuN8zYA

Extract code: `ffmpeg -i video.webm -vf fps=25 thumb%04d.jpg -hide_banner`

Video make: `ffmpeg -r 25 -i thumb%04d.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4`

Comment: Are you using the same bitrate, crf, preset, pixel format, etc. as the original video? See [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: The original video is compressed while your processed frames are not compressed.  Even though less frames. each frame contains more bytes making the results larger.

Comment: Should i use the same bitrate, .. , etc as the orginal video or not?

Comment: So i have to compress the frames or the video?